# Sql Trigger Using Next_Day Function

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that will check if the Tutor has accumulated 15 hours of tutoring for particular week every time a new record is made. Each record on the table is equal to an hour. 15 records for a particular tutor means 15 hours. I can get it to count all the records for a tutor but it should count records within the week based on the date being inserted with the insert function.

```
Create or replace Trigger Tutor_15hr_Rule
Before Insert on Meeting
For each row
Declare
HoursWorked binary_integer;
begin
select count(TutID)
into HoursWorked
from Meeting
where TutID = :new.TutID AND MeetDate Next_Day (:new.MeetDate, 'Saturday');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(HoursWorked);
if (HoursWorked + 1) > 15 then
Raise_application_Error(-20002, 'exceeded no of hours');
end if;
end;
/
show error;
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who can shed some light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use to_char with various format models to convert dates to year and week along with a lot of other options.

```
SELECT to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY IW') FROM DUAL
```

To change the beginning of the week you can add days before conversion:

```
SELECT to_char(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '2' DAY,'YYYY IW') FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Thanks for your response mate. I added a 'WorkWeek' attribute in my table that will keep track of which work week the record belongs to based on the MeetDate value then I tried the following code for the where clause in my trigger but now I'm getting an error when I try to insert any data into the table. What am I doing wrong here?

code: where TutID = :new.TutID AND WorkWeek = (Select to_char(MeetDate, 'YYYY IW') From Meeting Where MeetDate = :new.MeetDate);

error: ERROR at line 1: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: figure it out. didn't know Dual was a default table I could use. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share the final code. Works perfectly!!! (Thanks Brian!)

```
Create or replace Trigger Tutor_15hr_Rule
Before Insert on Meeting
For each row
Declare
HoursWorked binary_integer;
begin
select count(TutID)
into HoursWorked
from Meeting
where TutID = :new.TutID AND WorkWeek = (Select to_char(:new.MeetDate, 'YYYY IW') From Dual);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(HoursWorked);
if (HoursWorked + 1) > 15 then
Raise_application_Error(-20002, 'exceeded no of hours');
end if;
end;
/
show error;
```